# Set Modern Page as a Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, modern-pages

Is there an easy way for a user to choose modern page as a home page on a team site?

More info:

- I've created a modern team site (O365 group) and was able to choose a classic wiki page as a home page using a button in the ribbon. But there is no such button on modern pages. That sounds like a huge drawback.

While writing the question, I've realized we can use this method:

- Activate Reporting feature (site collection)
- Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Feature (site collection)
- Activate SharePoint Server Publishing feature (site level)
- "Welcome page" will appear in site settings. Use it to choose any URL for a home page.

I guess, we can also do it via CSOM:

```
var ctx = web.Context;
var rootFolder = web.RootFolder; 
rootFolder.WelcomePage = "/SitePages/newHome.aspx";
rootFolder.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

But is there any other easy way for common users to do it themselves? Something like a button in the ribbon would would be great. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set a modern page as the home page.   Go to the pages library. Select the desired page, on the top click ... you will see  'Make homepage' button.

[image][image]

Other way is right click on file for options and select the "Make homepage" option.
[image]

Comment: Just additional input you can also do this by clicking `...` right next to the file name.

Comment: Great Explanation @S Merchant! We really appreciate this type of answers :) Please Keep up :)

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti Thanks for fixing.  I was about to edit this. :)

Comment: @SMerchant, thank you. I didn't guess to try to find in in the modern page view. Classic view didn't have this option at all. Great to know there is an easy fix for this task

Comment: Thanks! Also, make sure to have the new desired page "Published" otherwise the "Make homepage" option won't appear.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your Site Pages library is using the New experience. You can enable it in Library settings >  Advance settings > List experience.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you create a new Site Page, make sure to Check In the page before you will see the "Set as Home Page" link show up in the modern ribbon.