# How to enable Modern Experience for new site home page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site

Apologies for this basic question. I recently created a new Team Site and would like it to use the Modern Experience. However, the home page for the site seems to default to the classic experience, even though the other pages use to the modern experience (see screenshots). I would ideally like all the pages to use the modern experience so my users aren't confused by the switches.

So, how do I change the Home page to use the modern experience?

Also, is there a setting I can update in SharePoint Admin so the home page of new sites defaults to be Modern Experience?

I tried Googling this, but couldn't find any perfectly clear answers (this Q&A seemed to suggest that you have to make a new site page and designate it as the homepage, but that seems roundabout to me: [Set Modern Page as a Home Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216932/set-modern-page-as-a-home-page)). Thanks!
[image: Classic Experience Home page]

[image: Modern experience page]

Comment: Here is a good [MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f) to read and troubleshoot your issue

Comment: Thanks for this helpful article! Still strange to me why it created a classic home page when I created I new modern team site, but oh well, at least I know how to fix it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the modern page as the Home page.

**Please follow steps:**

1. Go to the Pages Library.
2. Select the desired page, click on the **┇** link to the right of the item, and then click on **"Make homepage"** button.

[image]

3. Then, go to the Home page, you can view this page is using the Modern Experience.

[image]